# Почему две команды if сравнения совмещаются?

Tags: python, json, if

```
@bot.command()
async def M1(message):
    with open('coins.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await start(users, message.author, message)

async def start(users, user, message):
    if users[str(user.id)]['coins'] > 3065000:
        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await delete_coins(users, message.author, 3065000)        
        await send(message)
    else:
        await message.channel.send('Недостаточно средств для покупки.')

    with open('coins.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not str(user.id) in users:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]['coins'] = 0

async def delete_coins(users, user, coin):
    users[str(user.id)]['coins'] -= coin

async def send(message):
    await message.channel.send(f'Да')  

@bot.command()
async def M2(message):
    with open('coins.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await start(users, message.author, message)

async def start(users, user, message):
    if users[str(user.id)]['coins'] > 2065000:
        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await delete_coins(users, message.author, 2065000)        
        await send(message)
    else:
        await message.channel.send('Недостаточно средств для покупки')

    with open('coins.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not str(user.id) in users:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]['coins'] = 0

async def delete_coins(users, user, coin):
    users[str(user.id)]['coins'] -= coin

async def send(message):
    await message.channel.send(f'Да2')
```

Отдельно команды работают правильно, но если их поместить в один код - то команда M1 будет выдавать значения команды M2, а именно вычитать число 2065000 и Да2, при команде M2 выдаёт всё из команды M2. Почему так?

Comment: так а @bot.command() декоратор что делает?

Comment: @RomanR делает функцию как команду

Answer (score 0):

В общем, если ты не ошибся с отступами в вопросе, то у тебя просто переопределяется функции, на те, что находятся ниже.  Python будет использовать то определение, которое будет находится ниже. Измени названия дублированных функций.

У тебя функции:

```
async def start(users, user, message):

async def update_data(users, user):

async def delete_coins(users, user, coin):

async def send(message):
```

переопределяются после `async def M2(message):` и соответственно при вызове `M1` используются они. Измени названия, например на `start2`, `update_data2` и т.д. и не забудь заменить из в тех местах, где их вызываешь.

Или как вариант, определяй функции локально внутри `M1` и `M2`:

```
@bot.command()
async def M1(message):
    with open('coins.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    async def start(users, user, message):
        if users[str(user.id)]['coins'] > 3065000:
            await update_data(users, message.author)
            await delete_coins(users, message.author, 3065000)
            await send(message)
        else:
            await message.channel.send('Недостаточно средств для покупки.')

        with open('coins.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    async def update_data(users, user):
        if not str(user.id) in users:
            users[str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(user.id)]['coins'] = 0

    async def delete_coins(users, user, coin):
        users[str(user.id)]['coins'] -= coin

    async def send(message):
        await message.channel.send(f'Да')
        
    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await start(users, message.author, message)

@bot.command()
async def M2(message):
    with open('coins.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)


    async def start(users, user, message):
        if users[str(user.id)]['coins'] > 2065000:
            await update_data(users, message.author)
            await delete_coins(users, message.author, 2065000)
            await send(message)
        else:
            await message.channel.send('Недостаточно средств для покупки')
    
        with open('coins.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    
    async def update_data(users, user):
        if not str(user.id) in users:
            users[str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(user.id)]['coins'] = 0
    
    async def delete_coins(users, user, coin):
        users[str(user.id)]['coins'] -= coin
    
    async def send(message):
        await message.channel.send(f'Да2')
        
    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await start(users, message.author, message)
```